# No Permission to save figures in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw a figure in Python and I wanna save it as a pdf file, but I face the error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'results.pdf'`. I have changed the directory but there is still the error. I used this format in the past and there was no problem. I would be thankful if you could help me know what the problem is.

```
figure(figsize=(8, 8/1.618))


plt.plot(R,X[:,1], label='Always', color= 'blue' )
plt.plot(R,Y[:,1],0, label='Never', color = 'green' )
plt.plot(R,Z[:,1], label='Randomized', color= 'red',linestyle='-.' )


plt.xlabel('Price')
plt.ylabel('Demand')
plt.xlim(np.min(R)-1, np.max(R)+1)
plt.ylim(0,6)
plt.legend()


plt.savefig("results.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the full file path like so:

```
plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\***\\result.pdf', bbox_inches="tight")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not solved.

Comment: I find the problem. The Anti-virus software was blocking python to save the figure!